# Why does the second destruction of the temporary object on the code below occurs before the message "End of f" is printed?

Tags: c++

The ([code below](https://wandbox.org/permlink/n8z1fumuAIljjGzk))

```
#include<iostream>
struct C { C() { std::cout << "C()\n"; } ~C() { std::cout << "~C()\n"; } };
void f() {
  C * pc = new C;
  using C2 = C;
  pc->C::~C2();     // OK, destroys *pc
  C().C::~C();      // undefined behavior: temporary of type C destroyed twice
  std::cout << "End of f\n";
}

int main(){
    f();
}
```

prints the following:

```
C()
~C()
C()
~C()
~C()
End of f
```

I understand the code has undefined behavior, but AFAICT, the second destruction of the temporary object only occurs after the message "End of f" is printed. What exactly is happening here?

Comment: Why are you manually calling destructors? I don't believe I've ever seen a use case where that was required. Every `new` needs a matching `delete`, which'll do the cleanup and call the destructor for you.

Comment: @scohe001 I used [this example](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#id.dtor-3) in the latest C++ draft

Comment: First, undefined behavior is undefined; the compiler is allowed to do anything at all with this program. Second, a temporary is destroyed at the end of the full expression in which it's created - basically, at the semicolon. So it's not surprising it's destroyed before the following statement - that's normal and expected.

Comment: Could be time-travelling UB. You should count yourself lucky that it didn't go back in time and kill someone's grandparents.

Comment: Bad question because **your obseration contredict shown output** and also because one **cannot conclude anything** from a  program that has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, even if you copied this from the standard, it's still undefined behavior, so the answer could be just *the compiler felt like it*.

However, I understand your question is why `End of f` is printed after the second `~C()` and not at the end of the scope (i.e. after the print).

The answer is that temporaries in an expression are destroyed when it ends. Since `C()` creates a temporary, it will be destroyed at the `;`.

Comment: You are both right. I'm accepting your answer because it came before the other. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have a contradiction.  Your title says the 2nd destruction occurs BEFORE the `End` message is printed, but your question text says it occurs AFTER instead.  But it is clear from your actual log output that it is occurring BEFORE, as it should be.

In the statement `C().C::~C();`, `C()` creates a temporary object.  A temporary object is destroyed at the end of the *expression* that created it.  So, the temporary goes out of scope and gets destroyed on the `;`.  You are *explicitly* calling the destructor before the temporary goes out of scope, and then the compiler is *implicitly* calling the destructor when the temporary does goes out of scope.  That is why you get 2 destructions.  Both before the `End` message is printed.

Comment: Well, this is a logical conclusion *(the same I would have)* but when a program has undefined behavior, it is not always logical what one would observe.